# Use serverless here-api in lambda to extract traffic flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, here-api, here-traffic

I deployed a traffic service on aws that uses a lambda function, but I have a hard time understanding how it works. For instance, I see that the lambda function contains .js files for traffic, but I don't understand what part I can edit to create proper requests for traffic flow based on geo-coordinates.

I found an article about [geocoding app](https://developer.here.com/tutorials/geocoding_aws/), but it felt a bit different from what I am trying to achieve. Which is to create a function just to retrieve the traffic flow information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you deploy the traffic application in lambda, you can retrieve the traffic info via the Lambda API gateway.

- https://.execute-api..amazonaws.com/Prod/traffic/api/traffic/
- https://.execute-api..amazonaws.com/Prod/traffic/api/traffic.maps/

More details can be found in the below two online doc:
https://github.com/heremaps/here-aws-sar/tree/master/serverlessFunctions/traffic

https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics_v6.1/example-flow-intro.html

If you are looking for the rendered live-traffic map tiles, I would suggest using map tile application: https://github.com/heremaps/here-aws-sar/tree/master/serverlessFunctions/maptile